# Passing Username and Password to Remote Server using sc query

Tags: windows, service, command-line

I'm trying to use sc query to check that the services I have on a remote server are running. Using sc query works fine on my local system, but my remote system requires a username and password at login. I saw that sc config and sc create have account name and password options, but I don't see how I can use these for my purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sc doesn't have this functionality. There are several ways one could go about this; sockets, ssh, etc. I chose to use psexec which can connect to remote machines and run the command line on the remote machines.

Comment: sc allows you to set username and password. http://superuser.com/questions/632113/how-can-i-start-a-service-on-a-remote-machine-using-a-different-user

Comment: @pasx You must have misunderstood that other discussion. sc only allows you to set the credentials the service will use, you can't provide other credentials for accessing the machine the service is running on (which is what the OP asked for). I know this is an old thread, but I couldn't help correct this as I was looking for the same thing. PsService helps.

Comment: @TravelingFox thanks for the info. I remember spending quite a bit of time on this issue. Now I understand why I got stuck trying to access the remote computer.